# read in csv-files with the same name from subdirectories in R

Tags: r, csv, merge, concatenation, subdirectory

I have 2 folders named facebookdata1 and facebookdata2. These folders contain CSV files, which have exactly the same name ("activities","user" and so on) and they count up to the same amount.

I have to read in and merge (rbind...) the equally named csv files from the 2 different folders into R.

I know I can read in all the csv files from one folder in by using this:

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
for (i in 1:length(temp)) assign(temp[i], read.csv(temp[i]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the job:

```
directories <- c("path/to/facebookdata1", "path/to/facebookdata2")
files <- lapply(directories, list.files, pattern="*.csv", full.names = TRUE)
files <- lapply(files, sort)
dat <- Map(function(x,y) { rbind(read.csv(x), read.csv(y)) },
    files[[1]], files[[2]])
```

Now they are list elements of dat.
If you want to assign them to the globalenv use

```
list2env(dat)
```

You can speed the process up by using `data.table` as follows:

```
require(data.table)
dat <- Map(function(x,y) { rbindlist(fread(x), fread(y)) },
        files[[1]], files[[2]])
```

Comment: I think it works! Running now:) lot of csv files and a lot of data to read:)

Comment: you can spead it up by using `data.table::fread` and `data.table::rbindlist` instead of base `read.csv` and `rbind` - See edit

Answer (score 0):

You just lack a rbind! I tidied up your variable names a bit by removing the ".csv".

```
files1 <- list.files(path = "facebookdata1/", pattern="\\.csv$")
files2 <- list.files(path = "facebookdata2/", pattern="\\.csv$")
if(length(setdiff(files1, files2))>0)
  stop("Actually, the two directories do not have the same files")

for (file in files1) {
  varname <- substr(file, start=1, stop=nchar(file)-4)
  data1 <- read.csv(file.path("facebookdata1", file))
  data1 <- read.csv(file.path("facebookdata2", file))

  assign(varname, rbind(data1, data2))
}
```

Comment: you are a godsent! I get the following error though: Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match

Comment: Check that data1 and data2 are what you expect. The error means that data1 and data2 do not have the same number of columns, which can mean 2 things: *either* the data is not read properly (e.g. the path is wrong and data2 is NULL, or is actually _not_ a csv and you have misread data), *or* the two files really do not have the same number of columns. In this case you could use `rbind.fill` from package `plyr` or `bind_rows` from package `dplyr` to still merge them and keep all  columns.

Comment: Also check the content of `files1` and `files2`, well, check that everything is what you expect them to be!