# How to merge (inner join) dataframes in different directories that share the same filename

Tags: r, list, merge, inner-join

I have multiple directories with multiple csv files.

```
dir1/file1.csv 
dir1/file2.csv
```

and

```
dir2/file1.csv 
dir2/file2.csv
```

dir2 contains every file that dir1 has, and more. There are thousands of files in each folder.

All files within dir1 have the same structure as do all files within dir2. Between the two directories, files share 1 column, titled 'frame'.

Therefore, my goal is to perform an inner_join on all of the files in dir1 that share the same exact filename in dir2 (based on the shared 'frame' column) and output this into a new directory.

File per file this would go like this:

**Example data in dir1:**

```
individual <- c("1","1","2","2","3","4","5","5")
x <- c(665,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,663,665)
y <- c(-474.5,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,-474.5,-472.5)
frame <- rep(1:8)
file1 <- data.frame(individual,x,y,frame)
```

**Example data in dir2:**

```
datetime <- c("2016-01-01", "2016-01-02","2016-01-03","2016-01-04","2016-01-05","2016-01-06", "2016-01-07","2016-01-08","2016-01-09","2016-01-10")
frame <- rep(1:10)
file1 <- data.frame(datetime,frame)
```

**Example join between the data,**

```
file1 <- inner_join(file1,file1,by = "frame").
```

Importantly, I want to keep the same name of the original csv file(s). I'm a bit stuck on how to get this to work on a large scale (i.e. performing on all files, but only when their names match)

I tried to use a modified answer from this link written by @rentrop

[read in csv-files with the same name from subdirectories in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913247/read-in-csv-files-with-the-same-name-from-subdirectories-in-r)

```
directories <- c("path1/to/file1.csv", "path2/to/file1.csv")
files <- lapply(directories, list.files, pattern="*.csv", full.names = TRUE)
files <- lapply(files, sort)
dat <- Map(function(x,y) { inner_join(read.csv(x), read.csv(y), by = "frame") },
    files[[1]], files[[2]])
```

This didn't work and got

```
  zero-length inputs cannot be mixed with those of non-zero length
```

Any advice on how to complete this task is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Use `Reduce` or `purrr::reduce` along with `merge` or `dplyr::*_join`?

Comment: How would you use reduce to only apply to matching file names in the different directories?

Comment: Why are different directories an issue? You already know the file path, read them using `read.csv` or `dplyr::read_csv`. This can be done before `reduce`, but may be in that function as well.

Comment: The different directories aren't an issue, I guess I'm more stuck with only performing this on files whose names match.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how. I certainly doubt this is elegant, so would still love to know if anyone has a better way, but it got the job done:

Step 1: List the files in each directory:

```
list1 <- list.files(here::here("path","to","data1"), pattern=".csv",recursive = T, full.names = T)

list2 <- list.files(here::here("path","to","data2"), pattern=".csv",recursive = T, full.names = T)
```

Step 2: Read in files while creating a column with the filename:

```
list1_files <- map2(map(list1, data.table::fread, sep=","), basename(list1), cbind)

list2_files <- map2(map(list2, data.table::fread, sep=","), basename(list2), cbind)
```

Step 3: Bind all data together, and inner_join by filename AND the desired column. Note that I did not change the filename column name from the step2 code, and in reality it's called V2 automatically (as of the time of this post). So for my example, would be by = c("V2","frame").

```
final_merge <- list(bind_rows(list1_files), bind_rows(list2_files)) %>%
  reduce(function(x, y) inner_join(x, y, by = c("filename","frame")))
```

I don't know if there's a way to do this within the list itself (1 df at a time, output in a new list), but this worked for my purposes.